# ВК API. Как получить ID людей при поиске?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, хочу получить идентификаторы людей при поиске людей в вк, но ответ не приходит, вот что делаю:

```
CookieDictionary cook = new CookieDictionary();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cook = null; cook = new CookieDictionary();
        var request = new HttpRequest();
        request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
        request.Cookies = cook;

        string Str = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?count=1000&city=374");

        HttpResponse response = request.Post(Str);
        textBox1.Text = response.ToString();

    }
```

использую библиотеку xNet

Comment: Странно. Я попробовал в браузере и получил такой JSON: `{"error":{"error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: no access_token passed.","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"users.search"},{"key":"count","value":"1000"},{"key":"city","value":"374"}]}}`

Comment: Раз браузеру ответ приходит, то проблема где-то на вашей стороне.

Comment: @VladD я авторизации не делал, может из-за этого?

Comment: _no access_token passed_: похоже на то

Comment: Может быть, имеет смысл использовать https://vk.com/dev/wp_sdk

Comment: А Вы не думали о том, что надо передавать **access_token**?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, авторизируйтесь одним из [этих](https://vk.com/dev/authentication) способов. Если правильно все сделаете, получите `access_token`, который и требуется передать.